# Export array values to a column in csv file in python

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I have this variable and its a single column of 16250 entries as shown

```
output_values
array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0])

output_values.shape
 and it is an array of (16250,)
```

I want to  write these values as column 14 of an csv file with path

```
filename = 'C:/Users/tmp/Desktop/test/input_file_data.csv'
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you give a few lines of your csv file?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to read in your file into pandas and append that column with something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/tmp/Desktop/test/input_file_data.csv')
df = df.assign(new_col=output_values)
df.to_csv('C:/Users/tmp/Desktop/test/input_file_data_appended.csv')
```

`new_col` would then be the name of the new column in the pandas data frame object `df`. This can be done with numpy genfromtxt as well but it requires more code.